# JavaScript Class references

Tags: javascript, node.js

Hello I have a question with how can I reference an array of one class in another class

I have the class queue and the class players
Queue will have an array of players

class player:

```
class Player {
    constructor(id, name) {
      this.id = id;
      this.name = name;
    }
  }

  module.exports = Player;
```

class Queue

```
const Match = require('./Match');
// Queue class is a queue system with players.
class Queue {
    constructor() {
      this.players = [];
    }

    // addPlayers add multiple players into queue
    addPlayers(players) {
      this.players = this.players.concat(players);
    }

    // addPlayer adds a single player into queue
    addPlayer(player) {
      this.players.push(player);
    }

    // removePlayers remove multiple players from queue
    removePlayers(players) {
      players.forEach(p => {
        this.removePlayer(p);
      });
    }

    // removePlayer removes a single player from queue
    removePlayer(player) {
      const index = this.players.findIndex(p => p.id === player.id);
      if (index > -1) {
        this.players.splice(index, -1);
      }
    }

    // getPlayers return players that are currently on queue
    getPlayers() {
      return this.players;
    }

    // makeMatch makes match with provided condition and removes
    // matching players from queue
    makeMatch(condition) {
      // make matched players
      const matchedPlayers = this.players.filter(condition);
      console.log(matchedPlayers);
      // remove matched players from this.players
      this.removePlayers(matchedPlayers);
      // return new Match with matched players
      return new Match(matchedPlayers);
    }
  }

module.exports = Queue;
```

Or it is unnecessary to reference this class within another class.

Comment: It's unclear what you mean by "*unnecessary to reference this class within another class*" - you are not referencing the `Player` class (constructor) anywhere in the `Queue` code?

Comment: Yes I haven't mentioned it yet because I have questions about how to do it
the queue is an array of players i don't know how i would do this ex:

construction () {
this.players = new Player ();
}

Comment: In this case it would not be a player array but only a

Comment: But your current code is working just fine, you can add and remove any players you want? The `players` array should be initialised to the empty array, no `new Player` creation necessary.

Comment: However, there is another case in your code where you already *are* referencing another class, namely `Match` - and you're doing that correctly. Just import it and call it when you need it. I can't see a reason why the `Queue` class would need to create new player instances though.

Comment: It's working, only my removeplayers method is with a problem that I haven't found a solution yet, I create a match from this queue (using a condition) and then I remove the players that meet that condition from this queue, but for some reason not is working, but not returning error and I don't know where I went wrong

Comment: So the best way to make this reference would be through functions like I did with the match?

Comment: Make *which* reference?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/715AyvHd

Comment: Could you look at these two classes?
I think I made a right reference in match, but I doubt how to refer to class match in matches class

Comment: Looks just fine to me. Does it work as expected?

Comment: Thanks bro, I was with this concern of referencing class because I will now adapt to use database sequelize to extract and add data

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In plain javascript, arrays can hold objects of any type so it is unnecessary to reference the Player class. If you want, you can check on the instance-type of an object, i.e. the constructor used to create the object, by using `instanceof` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof). E.g. in your addPlayer:

```
addPlayer(player) {
  if(player instanceof Player) {
    this.players.push(player);
  } else {
    throw new Error('Only players can be added to the queue')
  }
}
```

Comment: [*Type*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/10.0/#sec-ecmascript-data-types-and-values) and *instance* are separate concepts. Type refers to data type, instance (in this case) refers to an object created from a constructor.

Comment: Thanks I think I understand, in case it becomes unnecessary to reference the player class within the class queue,

another example i have a class match and a matches:

and I have this code in the matches class:

class Matches {
    constructor () {
      this.matches = {};
    }
  
    addMatch (match) {
      this.matches [match.id] = match;
    }
    // Matches rest methods ...
  }

so I could do instance of no add match?

Even if I want to work with data persistence in the database wouldn't it be interesting to use any references to class?

Comment: If you want type-safety (at compile-time), which is what I understand you are asking about, you might want to look at something else than javascript. I would suggest TypeScript.